# How to get returned text from model to a controller on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.3

how to grab / get returned text from my model function to a controller ?? i'm using Laravel 5.3 Framework
example :

```
//My Model
Class MyModel Extends Model{
   function myFunction(){
       if($a == $b){
          $text = "a = b";
          return $text;
       }
       else if($a != $b){
          $text = "a ! b";
          return $text;
       }
       else{
          $text = "Some Text";
          return $text;
       }
   }
}
```

and in my controller is like this :

```
//My Controller
Class MyController extends Controller{
   public function test(){
     $obj = new MyModel;
     $data = $obj->myFunction();
     var_dump($data); // i want get returned from myFunction()
   }
}
```

please help me :D

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: @Muhammad.what is the issue or error you getting because its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me.You have assign value `$a` and `$b`
In your model

```
 public function myFunction($a,$b){

       if($a == $b){
          return "a = b";
       }
       else if($a != $b){
          return "a ! b";
       }
       else{
          return "Some Text";
       }
   }
```

Controller

```
$obj = new MyModel;
     $data = $obj->myFunction(1,2);
     var_dump($data);
```

Result

```
string(5) "a ! b"
```

You can also use static method in model

```
public static function myFunction($a,$b){

       if($a == $b){
          return "a = b";
       }
       else if($a != $b){
          return "a ! b";
       }
       else{
          return "Some Text";
       }
   }
```

In your controller

```
$data = User::myFunction(1,2);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: how about if i create a new variable ?? how to call it ?
example:
return $message = "some text"

Comment: @can you explain a bit .i didnt got you

Comment: @MuhammadBima.Pleas tell what error you getting because your code works fine .only you have not assigned to value to $a and $b

Comment: check my answer below your answer

Answer (score 0):

@iCoders

i don't have a problem when passing a value from controller to a model using a parameter. but my question is :

how to access variable $text from model to controller ?? i'm already used :

```
var_dump($data->text);
```

but the error is

> undefined property text

in my project, i used 2 variables from model to controller
my first variable, for my data from database
my second variabel ($text), for the respond for sweetAlert message

hope you can understand what i'm talking about

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. This is not how SO works. If you want to update your question then you can use the edit button in your question itself.